# django module "ImportError could not import settings" ratticweb.settings

Tags: python, django, docker, mod-wsgi

i am trying to run RatticDB Passwordtool in a Docker Container on our VPN Server. Only reachable over a specific Port and VPN.

When i try to reach the Webpanel of my App, i get the following errors from apache. 
I am no Python Developer, and thats why i cant figure out, why it cant import the settings from the manage.py

Thats how my manage.py looks

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "ratticweb.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

and apache2 error.log >>

```
[Thu Jul 16 08:26:38.326535 2015] [:error] [pid 10082:tid 140394318771968] [remote 10.150.0.6:29714]     % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
[Thu Jul 16 08:26:38.326560 2015] [:error] [pid 10082:tid 140394318771968] [remote 10.150.0.6:29714] ImportError: Could not import settings 'ratticweb.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named ratticweb.settings
[Thu Jul 16 08:26:39.320769 2015] [:error] [pid 10083:tid 140394276775680] [remote 10.150.0.6:10021] mod_wsgi (pid=10083): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/apps/ratticweb/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Jul 16 08:26:39.320843 2015] [:error] [pid 10083:tid 140394276775680] [remote 10.150.0.6:10021] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Jul 16 08:26:39.320866 2015] [:error] [pid 10083:tid 140394276775680] [remote 10.150.0.6:10021]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__
[Thu Jul 16 08:26:39.321025 2015] [:error] [pid 10083:tid 140394276775680] [remote 10.150.0.6:10021]     self.load_middleware()
[Thu Jul 16 08:26:39.321044 2015] [:error] [pid 10083:tid 140394276775680] [remote 10.150.0.6:10021]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 44, in load_middleware
[Thu Jul 16 08:26:39.321175 2015] [:error] [pid 10083:tid 140394276775680] [remote 10.150.0.6:10021]     for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
[Thu Jul 16 08:26:39.321192 2015] [:error] [pid 10083:tid 140394276775680] [remote 10.150.0.6:10021]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
[Thu Jul 16 08:26:39.321296 2015] [:error] [pid 10083:tid 140394276775680] [remote 10.150.0.6:10021]     self._setup(name)
[Thu Jul 16 08:26:39.321312 2015] [:error] [pid 10083:tid 140394276775680] [remote 10.150.0.6:10021]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 49, in _setup
[Thu Jul 16 08:26:39.321340 2015] [:error] [pid 10083:tid 140394276775680] [remote 10.150.0.6:10021]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Thu Jul 16 08:26:39.321354 2015] [:error] [pid 10083:tid 140394276775680] [remote 10.150.0.6:10021]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
[Thu Jul 16 08:26:39.321379 2015] [:error] [pid 10083:tid 140394276775680] [remote 10.150.0.6:10021]     % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
[Thu Jul 16 08:26:39.321400 2015] [:error] [pid 10083:tid 140394276775680] [remote 10.150.0.6:10021] ImportError: Could not import settings 'ratticweb.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named ratticweb.settings
[Thu Jul 16 08:39:35.490918 2015] [:error] [pid 10083:tid 140394411173632] [remote 10.150.0.6:31762] mod_wsgi (pid=10083): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/apps/ratticweb/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Jul 16 08:39:35.491024 2015] [:error] [pid 10083:tid 140394411173632] [remote 10.150.0.6:31762] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Jul 16 08:39:35.491100 2015] [:error] [pid 10083:tid 140394411173632] [remote 10.150.0.6:31762]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__
[Thu Jul 16 08:39:35.491271 2015] [:error] [pid 10083:tid 140394411173632] [remote 10.150.0.6:31762]     self.load_middleware()
[Thu Jul 16 08:39:35.491294 2015] [:error] [pid 10083:tid 140394411173632] [remote 10.150.0.6:31762]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 44, in load_middleware
[Thu Jul 16 08:39:35.491352 2015] [:error] [pid 10083:tid 140394411173632] [remote 10.150.0.6:31762]     for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
[Thu Jul 16 08:39:35.491386 2015] [:error] [pid 10083:tid 140394411173632] [remote 10.150.0.6:31762]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
[Thu Jul 16 08:39:35.491444 2015] [:error] [pid 10083:tid 140394411173632] [remote 10.150.0.6:31762]     self._setup(name)
[Thu Jul 16 08:39:35.491469 2015] [:error] [pid 10083:tid 140394411173632] [remote 10.150.0.6:31762]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 49, in _setup
[Thu Jul 16 08:39:35.491506 2015] [:error] [pid 10083:tid 140394411173632] [remote 10.150.0.6:31762]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Thu Jul 16 08:39:35.491522 2015] [:error] [pid 10083:tid 140394411173632] [remote 10.150.0.6:31762]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
[Thu Jul 16 08:39:35.491556 2015] [:error] [pid 10083:tid 140394411173632] [remote 10.150.0.6:31762]     % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
[Thu Jul 16 08:39:35.491620 2015] [:error] [pid 10083:tid 140394411173632] [remote 10.150.0.6:31762] ImportError: Could not import settings 'ratticweb.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named ratticweb.settings
```

Any idea on how to fix this?
I saw serveral Topics with this kind of Problems, but their issues had another source.

if i check the paths ... it seems fine

```
    >>> import sys
>>> for path in sys.path: print path
... 

/opt/apps
/opt/apps/manage.py
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Comment: So `ratticweb.settings` is on your `sys.path`?

Comment: i dont know. thats my first time using python and django. How can i check that out? I thought it would import that on its own

Comment: There should be a folder in the same directory as `manage.py` named `ratticweb`, and a file inside that folder two files; `__init__.py` and  `settings.py`

Comment: yep its inside there.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally your project path should be in python sys path, check this out to fix this [ImportError: Could not import settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987648/importerror-could-not-import-settings)

Comment: I saw that Topic already, and i think if the path is set in python like here it should work? `code >>> import sys
>>> for path in sys.path: print path
... 

/opt/apps/manage.py
/opt/apps
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages `

Comment: You can add the appropriate path (the folder containing `ratticweb.settings`), like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14876533/3714940) to the above linked question.

Comment: i did it, but no fix. do i need to change it the same way in the manage.py?