# problems setting up django's django-admin,py

Tags: python, django, macos, python-2.7

I'm attempting to use `django-admin.py loaddata` to seed a database on a dev server. I am using `django 1.7.1`. After symlinking the file to my project, when I tried to run the command I got this error:

`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting USE_I18N, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.`

Which lead me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082128/improperlyconfigured-you-must-either-define-the-environment-variable-django-set) question. So I attempted the recommended solution of `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=inventory_manage.settings`. However when I tried to run the `loaddata` command again, I was met with this `ImportError`:

`ImportError: Could not import settings 'inventory_manager.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named inventory_manager.settings`

Further [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987648/importerror-could-not-import-settings) lead to checking if my site was on the `sys.path` for my virtualenv. Which it was:

```
/Users/Aaron/Development/inventory-manager <--This is it
/Users/Aaron/.virtualenvs/inventorymgr/lib/python27.zip
/Users/Aaron/.virtualenvs/inventorymgr/lib/python2.7
/Users/Aaron/.virtualenvs/inventorymgr/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/Users/Aaron/.virtualenvs/inventorymgr/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/Users/Aaron/.virtualenvs/inventorymgr/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/Users/Aaron/.virtualenvs/inventorymgr/Extras/lib/python
/Users/Aaron/.virtualenvs/inventorymgr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/Users/Aaron/.virtualenvs/inventorymgr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/Users/Aaron/.virtualenvs/inventorymgr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7 

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
 /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
    /Users/Aaron/.virtualenvs/inventorymgr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Yet when I run the `loaddata` command, I'm still getting the same `ImportError`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to already be inside your python project root directory, and you should use `python manage.py loaddata`; which will [setup the environment for you correctly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/):

> In addition, manage.py is automatically created in each Django
>   project. manage.py is a thin wrapper around django-admin that takes
>   care of several things for you before delegating to django-admin:
>
> - It puts your project’s package on sys.path.
> - It sets the
>     DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable so that it points to your
>     project’s settings.py file.
> - It calls django.setup() to initialize
>     various internals of Django.

Answer (score 2):

You should only ever use `django-admin.py` to create the project. After that, always use `manage.py`, since it points to your actual project settings.